# Subset by date in R

Tags: r

I am trying to make a subset from my data frame excluding those previous to 01/01/2012.
The date format is in `%d-%-m-%y` and the program already knows it is a date.
The data frame is `TA`, the variable is `DATE_OLD`. 
I have tried : 
`new <- subset(TA, TA$JDATE_OLD<"01-01-2012")`, with obvious no success.

It returns me that `$` is an invalid operator for atomic vectors.
Any help would be apreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Please show some example data using (`dput`) and expected result based on that.   It may be that your dataset is a matrix.  Also, convert to date format i.e. `TA$JDATE_OLD <- as.Date(TA$JDATE_OLD, format ='%d-%m-%Y')` before subsetting.

Comment: akrun is right  of course, you need to put a *lot* more effort into asking a question. Best is to post a complete example.

Answer (score 4):

You need to have the proper comparison.

Let's start with an arbitrary data frame:

```
R> df <- data.frame(date=seq(as.Date("2015-01-01"), \
+                         as.Date("2015-12-01"), by="month"), \
+                   value=1000+(0:11)*42)
R> df
         date value
1  2015-01-01  1000
2  2015-02-01  1042
3  2015-03-01  1084
4  2015-04-01  1126
5  2015-05-01  1168
6  2015-06-01  1210
7  2015-07-01  1252
8  2015-08-01  1294
9  2015-09-01  1336
10 2015-10-01  1378
11 2015-11-01  1420
12 2015-12-01  1462
R>
```

Now, if you want all dates past August, you simply do index for greater-equal the cut-off value -- and make sure it is a `Date` type too:

```
R> df[ df$date > as.Date("2015-08-01"), ]
         date value
9  2015-09-01  1336
10 2015-10-01  1378
11 2015-11-01  1420
12 2015-12-01  1462
R>
```

Comment: I never understood why really but just `df[ df$date > "2015-08-01", ]` also works.

Comment: There is probably a dispatching function that calls `as.Date()` on the character string given the LHS of the comparison.  I use `POSIXct` more often than `Date` and am pretty sure you have to explicit there.  But I could well be wrong...